# On click the Universal link not giving complete URL in Swift xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am implementing the Universal link on my app. I followed all the instruction from following link. [AASA creation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains) to create AASA file.

The file content is as follows:

```
{
"applinks": {
  "details": [
       {
         "appIDs": ["44SGDK39BN.com.app.appname"],
         "components": [
           {
              "#": "no_universal_links",
              "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
           },
           {
              "/": "/men/*",
              "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /buy/"
           },
           {
              "/": "/women/*",
              "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/website/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
           },
           {
              "/": "*",
              "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/ and which has a query item with name 'articleNumber' and a value of exactly 4 characters"
           }
         ]
       }
   ]
  }
 }
```

it is uploaded on my server without redirect.

my entitlements file is like below image. i have attached that entitlements file.

[image: entitlements file]

and enabled the Associated Domains and added required domains in Signing and Capabilities. the following image refers that part.

[image: siging and capabilities and enabled Associated Domains]

And then i have updated the URL type in `Info` tab from `Project target explorer`

and then i am using following code on AppDelegateClass:

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
   

       guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
       let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
        
       let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
          return false
        }
       print(url)
     
       print("Path string \(components.path)")
      }
    }
```

Here `print(url)` prints only domain name, and `print("Path string \(components.path)")` prints just /. I dont know where i missed. I want complete url when the user click on particular link.

Example Url for universal link: `www.domainame.com/men/belt/beltname`

when the use click this type of link, this method prints only `www.domainname.com`

i need complete url. but, i faced this problem. i couldn't able to find the solution past two days. Anybody finds the solution. please suggest me.

**IS REVERSED DOMAIN NAME should be the bundle id for the app? will it be problem for it?**

My domain name is not reversed name of app bundle id.

**UPDATE**

when i adding the parameter, like follows,

`www.domainname.com\men?test=test`

I am getting complete path.

Again i dont know where i stuck.

Comment: I wonder whether you are telling the truth. I would expect it to be the other way around: `www.domainname.com\men` would yield `www.domainname.com`, because the backslash  is not a URL character so the URL would be ended at that point.

Comment: Also if I were you I would delete those `comment` entries, because they are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

After the long search through, I found the solution for it.

There was two type of problem.

1. there was no matching Signing iOS development certificate found.

I figured out and coordinate with client to make it. then this solved.

2. There was AASA file update. Actual one was not working for me.  i followed following links.

[using paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1)

[using component](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains)

nothing helped me. then

Constructed like below:

```
{
  "applinks": {
  "details": [
               {
                 "appIDs": [ "4QE5RGHDNN.com.app.iosapp"],
                 "components": [
                                 { 
                                     "/": "/*",
                                     "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /buy/"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "/": "*",
                                     "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /buy/"
                                  },
                                ],
                  "paths": [ "*"]
                }
             ]
           } 
   }
```

Above AASA file working perfectly.